# Imagemagick Cannot remove black around corners

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

This is the initial image:

[image]

I wanted to severely round the corners of an image without having jagged edges but i can't remove the black around them.

`convert image.jpg '(' +clone -crop 64x64+0+0  -fill white -colorize 100% -draw 'fill black circle 60,60 60,0' -background transparent -alpha shape '(' +clone -flip ')' '(' +clone -flop ')' '(' +clone -flip ')' ')' -flatten image.png;`

Anyone has an ideea? I tried -background transparent and other stuff and it's not working.

[image]

**The result i want is the image to have severely rounded corners without the black around them.**

Comment: Your title says you cannot remove rounded corners. The text of your question says you want to add rounded corners but they are jaggy. I have no idea how the picture relates to your question - is that what you start with? Or the result you are hoping for? Or a failed attempt? Please try to be clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @MarkSetchell, i've updated the question.

I just need to remove the black around the rounded corners.

Comment: I still don't understand. If that is the image you start with, please show the result you are hoping for. If it represents the result you hope for, please show what you started with.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've added the initial image. The result i want is the image to have rounded corners without jagged edges and without that black around the corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

Used:
`convert image.jpg '(' +clone -alpha extract '(' -size 100x100 xc:black -draw 'fill white circle 100,100 100,0' -write mpr:arc +delete ')' '(' mpr:arc ')' -gravity northwest -composite '(' mpr:arc -flip ')' -gravity southwest -composite '(' mpr:arc -flop ')' -gravity northeast -composite '(' mpr:arc -rotate 180 ')' -gravity southeast -composite ')' -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite -compose over '(' +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+5+5 ')' +swap -background none -layers merge -rotate 1 image.png;`

Now it looks like this
[image]